# Connecting ontology to a pre-exisiting database

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection, ontology

My friends and I are developing this hospitals' research system that depends on semantic search and ontology. The development plan states that we should draw the system's ontology and connect it to an existing database (hospital's database) that we already got from a real hospital.

We've searched the internet to find a way to connect the drawn ontology to the database that was **created beforehand**. But up till now, the only things that we have found shows that the drawn ontology creates the database itself. No results for connecting ontology with a database that wasn't created by the ontology.

I wanted to know if ontology offers this feature (connecting to an exisitng database)? Maybe it can connect to the database by adding an attribute/field to the exisiting database, so it doesn't have to go through the process of creating a database?

**Edit:
The database we are using is MySQL database (MySQL 5.7.10.0)**

Comment: What do you mean by "ontology creates the database itself"? It looks like you are using some tools (e.g. something that creates an "empty database" based on the ontology) that you have not mentioned in the question. This information might change the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have an existing relational database (MySQL) and need to "connect" it to your ontology. This means you need to map the information contained in the DB into ontology's concepts (classes and properties).

These mappings can be defined in either R2RML (a W3C standard) or D2RQ mapping language:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/r2rml/
- http://d2rq.org/

You will need to define the mappings (for your particular DB and ontology structure) and a tool (such as the D2R server) that can take these mappings and provide access to the database using the ontology that you developed.

*Update:* Tutorials / helpful resources for mapping relational DBs to OWL ontologies:

- [D2R Server tutorial (with examples)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150507134308/http://sw.cs.technion.ac.il/d2rq/tutorial)
- [RDB2OWL](http://rdb2owl.lumii.lv/) - DB to OWL mapping language and a tool for converting RDF2OWL mappings into D2RQ mappings

The second approach (RDB2OWL) is different from D2RQ or R2RML: in it you add annotations (with database mappings) to the ontology itself. You may have to explore them in more detail to see which approach is best for you.

Comment: Thank you so much, do you recommend us mapping tutorials for total beginners? Up till now we couldn't find one that helps explaining the basics.

Comment: @Ciba please also answer the comment under your question. that would clarify things. meanwhile, I will look at R2RML / D2RQ resources.